# SoapFaultClientException: outputting detail

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have a org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException object. I would like to get the detail contained therein for logging purposes but am finding it difficult to identify how to do this.

The exception.getFaultStringOrReason() method will give me a basic error message. However, I need to get further details which are held in the object's fault details. The SOAP response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>The values from the client failed to pass validation.</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <Errors>
      <Error reason="Required on input.">
        <ErrorLocation>
          <Node level="1" name="MyElement"/>
          <Node level="2" name="MyField"/>
        </ErrorLocation>
        <Parameters/>
        <StackTrace/>
      </Error>
    </Errors>
  </detail>
</soap:Fault>
```

I've got as far as iterating through a number of org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFaultDetailElement objects but I cannot get the details contained therein. Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
} catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
    log.error(e);
    SoapFaultDetail soapFaultDetail = e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail();
    SoapFaultDetailElement detailElementChild = (SoapFaultDetailElement) soapFaultDetail.getDetailEntries().next();
    Source detailSource = detailElementChild.getSource();

    try {
        return (JAXBElement<SearchResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(detailSource).getValue();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot unmarshal SOAP fault detail object: " + soapFaultDetail.getSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the SearchResponse class that is being unmarshalled above?

Answer (score 0):

More general version of gamepudi's method:

```
public <T> T soapFaultClientExceptionToCustomError(SoapFaultClientException e) {
    try {
        SoapFaultDetail soapFaultDetail = e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail();
        SoapFaultDetailElement detailElementChild = soapFaultDetail.getDetailEntries().next();
        Source detailSource = detailElementChild.getSource();
        T customError = ((T) getWebServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(detailSource));
        return customError;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot unmarshal SOAP fault detail object: " + soapFaultDetail.getSource());
        return null;
    }
}
```